# Interpretation of a proof by contrapositive in a small subset of the integers

Tags: analysis, integers, formal-proofs

So, i'm having a little problem on interpretating a result that i'm obtaining regarding a proof by contrapositive. Suppose we want to prove, by contrapositive, the following statements:

Let $S$ = $\{2, 3, 4\}$,  and let $n$ $\in$ $S$. If $\frac{n^2(n-1)^2}{4}$ is even, then $\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}$ is even.

$\underline{Proof}$:(by contrapositive)

Assuming $n$ is odd, $n$ can be written as $n = 2k + 1$, where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Since in $S$ we have not that many elements in $S$, we can verify for every element $n \in S$ that what we are trying to prove is true. So let's do the cases:

- $n = 2$: $\frac{2^2(2+1)^2}{4} = \frac{4.3^2}{4} = 9$, which is odd;
- $n = 3$: $\frac{3^2(3+1)^2}{4} = \frac{9.4^2}{4} = 36$, which is even;
- $n = 4$: $\frac{4^2(4+1)^2}{4} = \frac{4^2.5^2}{4} = 100$, which is even;

From our goal, now we want to take $n = 2 \in S$, and verify if $\frac{n^2(n-1)^2}{4}$ is odd.

Then, $\frac{2^2.(2-1)^2}{4} = \frac{4.1^2}{4} = 1$, which is odd.

Finally, the implication holds for $n = 2$. $\square$

My question now is the following: when we try to do this proof by construction, we see that the direct implication does not hold for $n = 2$. With that in mind, i've been trying to understand two things:

1. What can we interpret from this, knowing that the proof by construction, that is, $P \Rightarrow Q$ is logically equivalent to $\sim Q \Rightarrow \sim P$?
2. I was hoping that when we would try $\{3, 4\}$ would satisfy the direct implication, but only $n = 4 \in S$ holds for this $(\Rightarrow)$ direction. Why is this the case, given that $n = 2$ satisfies the contrapositive implication?

Comment: Your theorem statement is incomplete.  Apparently you want to deduce something about $\frac {n^2(n+1)^2}4$.  What?  And since $S$ only has three elements, why not just check each?

Comment: Thank you for the correction. I wanted to prove, that if that first thing is even, then the second is even. And i did it for all the cases. My question is more of something like: if it only works for n = 2 with the contrapositive, what can we conclude for n = 3 or n = 4 in case we wanted to show a direct proof. I think maybe it's better to ask this way. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Ok.  In that case, the contrapositive argument is fine.  Since $n=2$ is the only case for which that second fraction is odd, that's the only case that could, in principle, have yielded a counterexample  As you demonstrate that it doesn't produce a counterexample, you are done.

Comment: @lulu thanks. But just one more thing. In proven that $n = 2$ is the only case for which the contrapositive is true, we cannot say anything about $ n = 3$ or $n = 4$ to prove the $(\Rightarrow)$ direction? That is, why is it the case that these two other values are not the answer to the fraction being even, then n is even?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  The only way the claim could be false would be if you could exhibit a case in which the first fraction is even but the second one is odd.  Therefore, we have two natural ways to prove the claim.  The "direct" approach would be to enumerate all the cases in which the first fraction is even, and confirm that in each such case the second one is even.  The "contrapositive" way to prove it would be to enumerate all the cases in which the second fraction is odd and confirm that in each such case the first one is also odd.  Both are valid.

Comment: Intuition problems tend to arise when the various sets are infinite (or at least extremely large).  The usual [Raven Paradox](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raven_paradox#:~:text=The%20paradox%20appears%20when%20these,%22all%20ravens%20are%20black%22!) is such an example...it is hard to intuit why presenting a green apple is evidence for the claim "all ravens are black" though it is clearly evidence for the equivalent claim "all non-black objects are non-ravens".  Here, of course, the "enumeration" arguments are daunting (there are a lot of ravens and there are even more non-black objects).

Comment: @lulu i see, now i think i'm beginning to understand it better. To clarify i little bit more, the thing is, i was thinking if the following could be reasonable: "if $n = 2$ proves the contrapositive to be true, what can we conclude about $n = 3$ or $n = 4$?". And, accordingly to what you're saying there's not much meaning in establishing this connection . Am i thinking correctly?